# Erro ao construir e ao executar o projeto, java web, com jpa e hibernate

Tags: java, java-ee, maven

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto Java Web, usando JPA, Hibernate e maven, e ao executar o projeto, ou ao construir o projeto eu obtenho a seguinte exceção:

```
cd E:\NetBeansProjects\mercadinho; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_161" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 install\""
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building mercadinho 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
The POM for unknown.binary:hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.1.Final:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:copy (default) @ mercadinho ---

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ mercadinho ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 1 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ mercadinho ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 29 source files to E:\NetBeansProjects\mercadinho\target\classes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 9.218s
Finished at: Mon Jun 04 10:42:13 GFT 2018
Final Memory: 28M/307M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project mercadinho: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type model.entidade.Funcionario_ -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Segue o meu arquivo pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mercadinho</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>mercadinho</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.1.Final</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>    

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
            <id>PrimeFaces-maven-lib</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library PrimeFaces-maven-lib</name>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

pom.xml modificado:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>mercadinho</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>mercadinho</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>  

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
        <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
        <id>PrimeFaces-maven-lib</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library PrimeFaces-maven-lib</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: O seu erro é `Attempt to recreate a file for type model.entidade.Funcionario_` - Talvez seja algo errado no seu `pom.xml`.

Comment: Ta OK @Vitor Stafura, vou colocar o arquivo pom

Comment: Tente desabilitar o annotation processing no Netbeans: botão direito no projeto > Build > Compiling e desmarque Enable Annotation Processing, caso ele esteja marcado. Dê OK e tente buildar novamente.

Comment: cara, eu não encontrei esta opção segui o seguinte passo: botão direito do mouse no projeto > propriedade > construir > compilar > e encontrei 3 caixas de diálogos: compilar ao salvar, gerar informações de depuração e reportar Usos de APIs Obsoletas, as 2 primeiras estão marcadas a ultima não.

Comment: Oi, obrigado por aceitar a minha resposta. Vim avisar que editei mais um detalhe nela devido ao fato do `hibernate-entitymanager` estar *deprecated*.

Comment: Bom, eu que agradeço sua resposta, meu problema foi resolvido, fiz as alterações no pom.xml, e funcionou tudo certo, embora não tenha conseguido baixar a dependência do java 8, usando jpa 2.1 e hibernate 5.2.10 final, porém funcionou com java 7.0, vou colocar na pergunta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema que você está tendo está principalmente nessa parte do `pom.xml`:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... Outras dependências aqui que não dizem respeito ao problema... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.1.Final</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

As dependências que são declaradas nesse trecho são as seguintes:

- `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final`
- `org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.1.Final`
- `org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.2.6.Final`
- `unknown.binary:hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.1.Final:SNAPSHOT` (*provided*)
- `org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.5.2`
- `org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor:2.5.2` (*provided*)

O primeiro problema é que você está misturando dependências de 4 versões diferentes do Hibernate (`5.2.10.Final`, `4.3.1.Final`, `5.2.6.Final` e essa coisa estranha com o SNAPSHOT). **Use apenas uma e somente uma versão.** A mais recente é a `5.3.1.Final`. Aliás, na versão `5.3.1.Final`, o `hibernate-entitymanager` encontra-se *deprecated*, sendo necessário o uso apenas do `hibernate-core`.

O segundo problema é que você só pode ter um *modelgen*. Esse *modelgen* é um processador de anotações que gera classes adicionais em tempo de compilação, como por exemplo, a classe `model.entidade.Funcionario_` a partir da classe `model.entidade.Funcionario` (perceba o `_` no final do nome da classe gerada). No entanto, você está tentando usar 3 *modelgen*s distintos. O resultado é que o segundo vai dar erro porque a classe a ser gerada já existe. **Esse é o erro de compilação que você tem.**

O terceiro problema é que uma vez que você só pode ter um *modelgen*, terá que escolher entre o do Hibernate ou o do EclipseLink, você não pode ter os dois. Se realmente precisar usar os dois, sugiro separar as classes que precisem do *modelgen* do Hibernate em um JAR ou módulo A a ser compilado separadamente e as classes que precisam do *modelgen* do EclipseLink em JAR ou módulo B também a ser compilado separadamente.

O quarto problema é que seja qual for o *modelgen* que você vá usar, ele deveria ser *provided*. O `org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.2.6.Final` não está *provided*.

O quinto problema é que esse `unknown.binary:hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.1.Final:SNAPSHOT` é uma aberração. Parece ser apenas uma duplicata definida de forma errada do *modelgen* do Hibernate. Não tem nenhum sentido usar isso. Isso parece ter sido colocado automaticamente pelo NetBeans no repositório que ele inventou `unknown-jars-temp-repo`. No entanto, isso é apenas uma gambiarra que o NetBeans faz para que JARs avulsos possam ser usados no Maven. Inclusive, veja a descrição desse repositório conforme está em seu `pom.xml`:

> A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.

Traduzindo (grifos meus):

> Um repositório temporário criado pelo NetBeans para bibliotecas e jars que ele não pôde identificar. **Por favor, substitua as dependências deste repositório pelas corretas e delete este repositório.**

Há também um sexto problema que é uma coisa diferente. Veja:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- ... Um monte de coisas omitidas aqui... -->

                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
```

Observe que em um deles você usa a versão `6.0` e no outro `7.0`.

Considerando-se tudo isso, ressalto que é recomendado usar-se variáveis para declarar as versões dos artefatos para facilitar a mudança delas quando necessário em um lugar só, evitando que fiquem incoerentes. Há uns anos atrás, já perdi alguns dias de trabalho batendo cabeça por causa de versões incoerentes que poderiam facilmente ser resolvidas se o projeto usasse essa abordagem. O `pom.xml` também fica mais fácil de ser lido e entendido quando artefatos diferentes da mesma versão de um mesmo projeto ficam juntos.

Um outro detalhe que noto é que a última versão do Hibernate que funcionava no Java 7 é a `5.1.14.Final`. Apesar disso, você já está tentando usar a `5.2.6.Final` e a `5.2.10.Final` que só rodam a partir do Java 8. Assim sendo, sugiro mudar o seu `maven-compiler-plugin` para Java 8 ao menos.

Também dá para colocar os plugins nas versões mais novas. `3.7.0` para o `maven-compiler-plugin`, `3.2.1` para o `maven-war-plugin` e `3.1.1` para o `maven-dependency-plugin`.

Nunca vi um caso onde faça sentido usar tanto o Hibernate quanto o EclipseLink no mesmo projeto, então acredito que você queira usar só o Hibernate e deixar o EclipseLink de lado. Portanto, o seu `pom.xml` ficaria assim:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mercadinho</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>mercadinho</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <hibernate.version>5.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.1-901.jdbc4</postgresql.version>
        <jsf.version>2.2.7</jsf.version>
        <primefaces.version>5.0</primefaces.version>
        <javaee.version>7.0</javaee.version>

        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <compiler.plugin.version>3.7.0</compiler.plugin.version>
        <war.plugin.version>3.2.1</war.plugin.version>
        <dependency.plugin.version>3.1.1</dependency.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- PostgreSQL. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSF. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Primefaces. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java EE. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>  

        <!-- Hibernate. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>  
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${war.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${dependency.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${javaee.version}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
            <id>PrimeFaces-maven-lib</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library PrimeFaces-maven-lib</name>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```